# What's the purpose of _.extend({})

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've seen the following Underscore extend usage:

```
_.extend({})
```

Wouldn't the result be just the same empty object? Is there a reason for doing this?

Comment: Can you show the context in which it's used?

Comment: Possibly wraps the object with some non-standard functionality?

Comment: @Emissary Underscore.js is not like jQuery, it doesn't wrap its data. It's just a bunch of convenience functions for working with native JS objects and arrays.

Comment: fair enough - then it looks pretty pointless.

Comment: Sorry, I can not find where I saw _.extend({}). But the spirit of the question is the same for the following code I lifted from the existing code. Why extend an object with itself?

var attributes = {
  firstname: $('#firstname').val(),
  lastname:  $('#lastname').val()
}

var newAttributes = _.extend(attributes);

Comment: So, the object is in fact not empty? Maybe the developer thought that it will create a copy of the object (which it doesn't). It is certainly not extending the object with itself, as you can find out by reading the documentation: http://underscorejs.org/#extend

Comment: I agree it's pointless. The original object is not used anywhere and the supposed copy (extend) is used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscore's [**`_.extend`**](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) function copies all properties from the second to nth argument into the first argument and returns the first argument.

So, `var foo = _.extend(bar);` does in fact nothing and `foo === bar`. There is no reason to do this.

I can only assume that the developer thought that the function would return a copy of the destination object.